# Port forwarding outgoing request with PF

Tags: macos, port-forwarding, bsd, pf

I'm trying to redirect all outgoing traffic from my local machine on port 843, to go to my local service on port 1234.

So, when I make a request to e.g. `1.2.3.4:843`, I want it to connect to `127.0.0.1:1234` instead (transparently to the requesting application).

I'm on OS X so I'm trying to achieve this using `pf`.

Here's what I have:

```
ext_if = "en0"
int_if = "lo0"

rdr on $ext_if inet proto tcp from self to any port 843 -> 127.0.0.1 port 1234
```

Now when I do `telnet 1.2.3.4 843` I would expect a connection on my local service (running on port 1234).

However it doesn't seem to redirect properly. Using `tcpdump` I can see that the packets are put on the interface with the destination `1.2.3.4`.

If I do localhost only rule, e.g.

```
rdr on $int_if inet proto tcp from self to any port 843 -> 127.0.0.1 port 1234
```

Then `telnet localhost 843` works as expected and I get the response from my local service which is listening on port  `1234`.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and now I'm at a loss of ideas. Any help/pointers is appreciated.

EDIT:

I've tested a bit more and it seems as with the last rule, any request that lands on the loopback interface works. So `telnet 127.2.3.4 843` also correctly redirects.

I tried adding `$ext_if` to above

```
rdr on { $ext_if $int_if } proto tcp from any to any port 843 -> 10.0.1.10 port 1234
```

But without success. I also added sysctl forwarding. Did nothing.

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
sudo sysctl -w net.inet6.ip6.forwarding=1
```

Comment: Had the same question, answered here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/421261/os-x-10-8-redirecting-locally-initiated-ssh-connections-to-localhost22

Answer (score 0):

As the comment said, `rdr` only handles incoming traffic, so you should redirect your outgoing traffic to 'incoming' traffic, i.e. redirect `out` to `lo0`.

Another problem you will encounter immediately in the following is the outgoing traffic of your local proxy is also redirected to itself, whichi is a infinite loop.

Here's a demo solving these problems, which copy from https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/#macos

```
#The ports to redirect to proxy
redir_ports = "{http, https}"

#The address the transparent proxy is listening on
tproxy = "127.0.0.1 port 8080"

#The user the transparent proxy is running as
tproxy_user = "nobody" 

#The users whose connection must be redirected.
#
#This cannot involve the user which runs the
#transparent proxy as that would cause an infinite loop.
#

rdr pass proto tcp from any to any port $redir_ports -> $tproxy
pass out route-to (lo0 127.0.0.1) proto tcp from any to any port $redir_ports user { != $tproxy_user }
```

**Some important notes**:

- MUST leave a trailing line after the last rule, or you'll get a syntax error by `pfctl`
- Run the proxy by the `tproxy_user` user, to avoid loop

I tested it with `mitmdump` on macOS 13 and worked